# Multi Timezone aware app with working hours

Tags: javascript, django, timezone, django-timezone

I am working on a mobile app which for the server side uses django and angularJS + phonegap on the client side.

My app relates to calendar based activities. So it is very timezone aware.

The problem I am facing now is that I have a feature which I set the working hours in a weekly format which means : Monday to Friday from 10:00 AM to 17:00 PM. This is a global working hours and are not attached to a specific date.

My problem is how to handle such working hours with timezones? TimeField in django does not have awareness to timeezone. How should I display to each of my users (depends on there timezone) the correct working hours while depends on their location ?

Answer (score 0):

[Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) is a Javascript library managing the time zone from moment.js. It may help you to solve your problem.